# VBA Error - Object doesn’t support this property or method

Tags: excel, object, methods, vba

I have a macro which runs well on my computer and few other peoples. However for some other users there getting an error message saying:

> “Object doesn’t support this property or Method”.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub Create_NewSheet_TopasteData() 
Dim test As Worksheet 
Sheets("Security Distribution").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
Set test = ActiveSheet 
test.Name = Range("F2")     
End Sub
```

Comment: The part of the code I believe that the issue is arising from is this: 
**bold**
Option Explicit
Sub Create_NewSheet_TopasteData()
    Dim test As Worksheet
    Sheets("Security Distribution").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set test = ActiveSheet
    test.Name = Range("F2")
End Sub
**bold**
I am copying a worksheet all together with its macro into different sheet.

Comment: @ katz please see above

Comment: I suggest you to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/4519059), and change your code to a compatible code that prevent you from such errors ;).

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

`test.Name = test.Range("F2")`

with

`test.Name = test.Range("F2").Value`

(tested with Excel 2007)

Comment: Thanks for that, good piece of advice. This code works on my computer but if I try it  on a different computer in the same team, it doesn’t work. I think it’s more down to Excel version or computer itself. I strongly believe that the code is ok. I am open opinions. @ katz

Comment: @James so are there different versions of excel installed on the other computers?

Comment: @ katz Just discovered we have different versions of OLE’s

Answer (score 0):

Your code is likely throwing an error on the line `test.name = Range("F2")`. Is there any data in cell `F2`? Note, since `Range("F2")` is not qualified, it is taking the information from the active sheet. So, make sure that the active sheet has an appropriate sheet name.

Comment: Just discovered we have different versions of OLE’s , so these have to be updated .